# Do something with subsequently created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a simple Django powered notetaking app and I'm using [martor](https://github.com/agusmakmun/django-markdown-editor) for markdown and syntax highlighting:

[image: screenshot]

so when you click on one of the notes, it gets displayed in the rightmost area. This currently works as follows: whenever you click one of the notes, an AJAX request is fired which calls a Django view that renders that specific part of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.note', function() {
    let clickedNote = $(this);
    const pk = clickedNote.attr('id');
    const url = Urls['notes:show-note']();
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: {
        'pk': pk
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $('.note-container').html(response);
        $('.note').each(function() {
          $(this).css({'background-color': 'white'});
        });
        clickedNote.css({'background-color': '#F9FAFC'});
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is how an example response looks like when rendered:

```
<div class="note-container">
  <h3>small Python snippet</h3>
  <div class="description martor-preview">
    <h1>Small Python snippet</h1>
    <pre>
      <code class="python">
        class App(tk.Frame):
            def spam(self):
                return 'eggs'
      </code>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

My issue is that that part of the page is not syntax-highlighted, because the elements are created subsequently. This is how I currently highlight the code blocks:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('pre').each(function(i, block){
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });    
  });
</script>
```

...so the elements that get created after that are simply not highlighted. I was wondering how can I do something with newly created elements, i.e. how can I highlight subsequently created code blocks?

Comment: I recommend trying a DOM Mutation Observer

Comment: @ControlAltDel no need for a DOM Mutation Observer when he can simply highlight the code in his ajax success handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the *hljs* syntax-highlighter after every ajax response (i.e. inside your ajax **success** handler):

```
  $.ajax({
    ...
      success: function(response) {
        $('.note-container').html(response);

        ...

        // *** syntax-highlight new <pre> tags ***
        $('.note-container pre').each(function(i, block) {
          hljs.highlightBlock(block);
        });

      });
    ...
```